# IN operator must be used with an iterable expression : For loop

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, standardcontroller, getcontent

I am getting Subject header error at below line. Can someone let me know what is the issue?

Line:

```
for (Compliance_Incident_abv__c myContact : [select ID,ManagerEmail_abv__c,RepEmail_abv__c,Rep_abv__c,Rep_abv__r.Name, Rep_abv__r.ManagerId,Rep_abv__r.Manager.Name from Compliance_Incident_abv__c  where ID in :oInc]) { blah blah }
```

Here oInc is as below.

```
oInc = (Compliance_Incident_abv__c) controller.getRecord();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oInc = (Compliance_Incident_abv__c) controller.getRecord();

Your oInc it is a SObject and in the IN clausule you need pass a List.

**Example1 ussing record id**

```
[select ID,ManagerEmail_abv__c,RepEmail_abv__c,Rep_abv__c,Rep_abv__r.Name, Rep_abv__r.ManagerId,Rep_abv__r.Manager.Name from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where ID = :oInc.Id];
```

**Example 2 (Ussing a List of ids)**

```
String[] idList = new String[]{oInc.Id};
[select ID,ManagerEmail_abv__c,RepEmail_abv__c,Rep_abv__c,Rep_abv__r.Name, Rep_abv__r.ManagerId,Rep_abv__r.Manager.Name from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where ID IN :idList];
```

Answer (score 4):

As per docs In can be used with

> The value of the IN or NOT IN operator in WHERE clauses, allowing
>   filtering on a dynamic set of values. Note that this is of particular
>   use with a list of IDs or Strings, though it works with lists of any
>   type.

In your case you are using In with single record thats why its giving this error. if you want to fetch single record then try `where Id =:oInc` or convert this oInc into this list and then pass it. Hope it will solve your problem.